# json as php variable

Tags: javascript, php, json

The current output looks like the below:

```
 {"place_id":"26693344","licence":"© LocationIQ.org CC BY 4.0, Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0","osm_type":"node","osm_id":"2525193585","lat":"-37.870662","lon":"144.9803321","display_name":"Imbiss 25, Blessington Street, St Kilda, City of Port Phillip, Greater Melbourne, Victoria, 3182, Australia","address":{"cafe":"Imbiss 25","road":"Blessington Street","suburb":"St Kilda","county":"City of Port Phillip","region":"Greater Melbourne","state":"Victoria","postcode":"3182","country":"Australia","country_code":"au"},"boundingbox":["-37.870762","-37.870562","144.9802321","144.9804321"]}
```

I am trying to get the place_id as a php variable like so

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
      echo $response['place_id'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = curl_exec($curl);    //Will get the json data
$data = json_decode($data,TRUE);    //will decode the json into associative arrays
echo $data['place_id'];
```

This should do what you want to accomplish. Tried. Comment if doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You have to decode json string with `json_decode`.

```
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response);
```

Keep in mind that the second parameter of the `json_decode` is the `$assoc`. When true, return while will be array, otherwise instance of `stdClass` will be returned:

```
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);
```

You can read more about json_decode on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: You are missing the `$assoc` flag. Simply use `$decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);`

Answer (score -1):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in order to convert json string to PHP object.

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
if ($err) {
   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
   $response = json_decode($response);
   echo $response->place_id;
}
```

Online working example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5f773b34649bef29c9bf6d84375e556c0faad5a

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Updated my response. ($response->place_id)